# Storybook Play not waiting for component to render

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, storybook

We have a menu item component that detects if it is on an active vue route, base on this is applies different classes. it uses a computed function to do this, we can see via logging that the computed is called twice, first it returns that it is not the current route and then it returns it is active. so it looks like the router is 'slow' to return the active route

when we try to test this with a play function it is getting the inactive classes first, then applying the active classes, so the assertion fails.

is there away for the play function to wait until all rendering is done.

This is the output for the play function:

```
expect(<a.border-transparent.text-gray-500.inline-flex.items-center.border-b-2.px-1.pt-1.text-sm.font-medium.hover:border-gray-300.hover:text-gray-700.cursor-pointer>).toHaveClass("border-indigo-500")
expect(element).toHaveClass("border-indigo-500")

Expected the element to have class:
  border-indigo-500
Received:
  border-transparent text-gray-500 inline-flex items-center border-b-2 px-1 pt-1 text-sm font-medium hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700 cursor-pointer
```

This is the component:

```
template>
  <router-link :to="href" :class="getClasses" aria-current="page">{{ hyperlinkText }}</router-link>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import assertStringIsNotBlank from "@/base/functions/asserts/strings/AssertStringIsNotBlank.ts";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "TopMenuDesktopNavLink",
  expose: [],
  props: {
    /**
     * HTML href attribute for link
     */
    href: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
      validator: (href) => assertStringIsNotBlank(href),
    },

    /**
     * Hyperlink component text
     */
    hyperlinkText: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
      validator: (text) => assertStringIsNotBlank(text),
    },
    isActive: {
      required: false,
      default: false,
      type: Boolean,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    getClasses() {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log("getclasses");
      let retVal;
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(this.$route.matched);
      if (
        this.$route.matched.some((route) => {
          return route.path === this.href;
        })
      ) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log("active");
        retVal = "border-indigo-500 text-gray-900";
      } else {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log("inactive");
        retVal = "border-transparent text-gray-500";
      }
      return `${retVal} inline-flex items-center border-b-2 px-1 pt-1 text-sm font-medium hover:border-gray-300
      hover:text-gray-700 cursor-pointer`;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

and this is our play file

```
import { expect } from "@storybook/jest";
import { within } from "@storybook/testing-library";
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/vue3";
import { vueRouter } from "storybook-vue3-router";

import TopMenuDesktopNavLink from "@/superAdmin/pages/components/TopMenuDesktopNavLink.vue";

type Story = StoryObj<typeof TopMenuDesktopNavLink>;

const meta: Meta<typeof TopMenuDesktopNavLink> = {
  title: "Super Admin/Pages/Components/TopMenuDesktopNavLink",
  component: TopMenuDesktopNavLink,
  tags: ["autodocs"],
  parameters: {
    layout: "centered",
  },
};

export default meta;

export const Default: Story = {
  render: (args) => ({
    components: { TopMenuDesktopNavLink },
    setup() {
      return { args };
    },

    template: '<TopMenuDesktopNavLink v-bind="args"/>',
  }),

  args: {
    href: "/Dashboard",
    hyperlinkText: "Dashboard",
  },

  play: async ({ canvasElement }) => {
    const canvas = within(canvasElement);
    expect(canvas.getByText("Dashboard").classList.contains("border-transparent")).toBeTruthy();
  },
};
const customRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/Dashboard",
    name: "da",
    component: TopMenuDesktopNavLink, // this would need to be defined/imported into the `.stories` file
  },
];
Default.decorators = [
  /* this is the basic setup with no params passed to the decorator */
  vueRouter(customRoutes),
];

export const Active: Story = {
  render: (args) => ({
    components: { TopMenuDesktopNavLink },

    setup() {
      return { args };
    },

    template: '<TopMenuDesktopNavLink v-bind="args"/>',
  }),

  args: {
    href: "/Dashboard",
    hyperlinkText: "Dashboard",
    isActive: true,
  },

  play: async ({ canvasElement }) => {
    const canvas = within(canvasElement);

    await expect(await canvas.findByText("Dashboard")).toHaveClass("border-indigo-500");
  },
};

Active.decorators = [
  /* this is the basic setup with no params passed to the decorator */
  vueRouter(customRoutes, {
    initialRoute: "/Dashboard",
  }),
];
```